# How do I add a 'continue shopping' button in Checkout/cart?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, redirect, shopping-cart, checkout-page

I've had a Magento site set up, but there is no '**Continue shopping**' button showing on the `Checkout/Cart` page. I want customers to have the option of going back into the store once they have added something to their cart. I've found lots of info on changing the 'Continue shopping' button, but can't find out how to add one in the first place.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: enable path hint, check template file and add button on that

Answer (score 0):

Go to `app/design/frontend/{yourpackage}/{yourTheme}/template/checkout/cart.phtml`  and add this piece of code below the `<form>` tag:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        ...
        <!--For the continue shopping-->
        <?php if($this->getContinueShoppingUrl()): ?>
            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?>" class="button btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <!--For the Update Shopping Cart-->
        <button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="update_qty" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart'); ?>" class="button btn-update"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart'); ?></span></span></button>

        <!--For the Clear Shopping Cart-->
        <button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="empty_cart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Clear Shopping Cart'); ?>" class="button btn-empty" id="empty_cart_button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Clear Shopping Cart'); ?></span></span></button>
        ...
    </fieldset>
</form>
```